# Can I change the exit code of the help command for Click in Python?

Tags: python-click

I'm attempting to convert my python from argparse to click.  Using no_args_is_help I can get click to return the --help message even when the command line is empty.  Whenever the help message is shown, the exit code that is passed to the system is still 0.  Is there a way to change the exit code for the help message in the Click context or command call?

Below is example code that functions the way I want in all ways other than exit code.  I could probably find a way to jerry-rig an exit change for when --help is called, but I can't see how to get under the hood enough to change the exit code for no_args_is_help.

```
import click

def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo(f"Hello {name}!")

        
@click.command(no_args_is_help=True)
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.',show_default=True)
@click.option('--name',help='The person to greet.',required=True)
def manual_run(count,name):
    hello(count,name)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manual_run()
```

Note, I would like the exit code to remain 0 for normal successful processing, and only change to 1 for a help-induced exit

I expected some kind of option along the lines of:
`@click.command(no_args_is_help=True, help_exit_code=1)`
but that doesn't work, and I can't find any documentation on editing the context of the help statement alone.

UPADTE:

It appears to work if you define a new command class with an overloaded get_help attribute:

```
class helpExit(click.Command):
    def get_help(self, ctx):
        helpstr=super().get_help(ctx)
        click.echo(helpstr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

and then pass that class in the command call:
`@click.command(no_args_is_help=True,cls=helpExit)`
Is this the best way to do this?